# How do i count the number of times A={Onion} and B={Kidney Beans,Eggs} occur in the dataset?

Tags: python, data-mining

[image]

How do i count the number of times A={Onion} and B={Kidney Beans,Eggs} occur in the dataset?

Comment: Please, add an answer to given dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataset

```py
dataset = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'], 
           ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'], 
           ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]
```

first we make the array flat and then we count the occurrences of each element

```py
flat_dataset = [item for sublist in dataset for item in sublist]
counter =  { item:flat_dataset.count(item) for item in flat_dataset }
```

Result:

```py
{'Milk': 3,
 'Onion': 4,
 'Nutmeg': 2,
 'Kidney Beans': 5,
 'Eggs': 4,
 'Yogurt': 3,
 'Dill': 1,
 'Apple': 1,
 'Unicorn': 1,
 'Corn': 2,
 'Ice cream': 1}
```

If you just want some specific keys use

```py
counter.get('Onion')
# 4
counter.get('Kidney Beans') + counter.get('Eggs')
# 9
```

if you want how many times 'Onions' appear at least once in each subarray

```py
sum(['Onion' in subset for subset in dataset])
# 3
```

if you want how many times ''Kidney Beans' and 'Eggs' appear together at least once in each subarray

```py
sum(['Kidney Beans' and 'Eggs' in subset for subset in dataset])
# 4
```

Comment: Note that this gives the sum of all occurrences of "kidney beans" and "eggs", neither the union (which would deduplicate) nor the intersection.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I modified the answer also taking into account your observation